# How do I get the rubber duck back?

Tags: support, quack-overflow

I want the SO rubber duck back! How do I make him come back? I asked a question, the duck answered, then gave me the options 'I have another question' and 'I hate this duck' and I selected 'I hate this duck' and now the duck is gone forever. :(

Comment: Maybe should have been a question in Meta? 

Comment: open in incognito mode or clear cache

Comment: There's a good answer here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/308575/how-do-i-reenable-quack-overflow-if-i-disabled-it/308576#308576

Comment: @yausername not good enough I want to tell him I hate him, AND have him here all the time.

Comment: @pep well that sounds like you are trying to have fun, and meta hates fun

Comment: So does the main site. I am prepared for the hate.

Comment: Surely you know by now.  "I hate you" is not a question.

Comment: @Jono2906 lame, I was hoping for a konami code-style way to make him come back. Like type a character sequence and say "I'm sorry rubber buddy".

Comment: You don't need to clear your cookies, a microphone or a konami code just channel your inner quack

Comment: It's actually a programming-related question, not sure why it has been migrated

Comment: The rubber duck will be with you, always.

Comment: https://unikong.github.io/quackoverflow/

Comment: @DonaldDuck  That is so brilliant :D

Comment: @Simon I got that link from [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/308630/349538).